# Get number of Lines in Modern UI TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a Modern UI (Metro) app and would like to display the number of lines that are inside the TextBox control.

Going through the documentation and Intellisense, and the Properties Pane for the selected TextBox control, I see that there appears to be no Lines property anymore. How can we do this? And why have they removed it?

Comment: It is trivial to implement.. what are you having trouble with?

Comment: Maybe you can count the number of line breaks in the content of the Textbox?

Comment: Sorry guys, I know it's a trivial task but my memory is a little fuzzy today. I just remembered how to count lines. And thanks @GianAcuna.

Comment: `TextBlock` has `Lines` property, I don't remember `textBox` having a `Lines` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst WinForms has TextBox.Lines, and WPF has TextBox.LineCount, Windows 8 Metro is closer to Silverlight, which doesn't have this capability. If you check the documentation you'll also note the lack of similar properties like WPF's TextBox.MaxLines.

If TextWrapping is off, and thus you have newline characters, you could manually count those, but if you've got wrapping then you're probably in trouble. You might be able to do some maths with ActualHeight and the font size.